# Make a Post request during middleware

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm new to Express JS and Node JS.

I intend to implement a Auth-Server in Express Middleware manually
I'm using https://github.com/ranm8/requestify to make the request

```
const requestify = require('requestify');
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
    var config = require('./config-' + process.env.REACT_APP_ENV)
    var redirect = config.ADMIN_UI_URL

    // Perform login to Auth-Server
    if (req.originalUrl.startsWith('/?code')) {
        let auth_code = req.query.code

        let params = {
            'grant_type': 'authorization_code',
            'code': auth_code,
            'client_id': config.OAUTH_CLIENT_ID,
            'redirect_uri': redirect
        }
        requestify.post(config.OAUTH_ID_URL+'/oauth2/token', params).then(function(response) {
            console.log(response.getBody()); // There is not data post to the Auth-Server
        });

        return res.redirect('http://google.com');
    }

    // Check Token
    if (req.cookies._token === undefined) {
        let url = config.OAUTH_ID_URL + '/oauth2/authorize?' + 'response_type=code' + '&' + 'client_id=' + config.OAUTH_CLIENT_ID + '&' + 'redirect_uri=' + redirect
        return res.redirect(url)
    }
    next()
})
```

I can check user token and recieve auth_code just fine. But I can not request a token out of logged-in user by making a post request to Auth-User

It seems like I miss understand how NodeJS, Epxress work, or some kind of the scope here

Please help me out! Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Try to check what is the error you are getting. add error handler like this

```
requestify.post(config.OAUTH_ID_URL+'/oauth2/token', params).then(function(response) {
            console.log(response.getBody()); // There is not data post to the Auth-Server
        }).error(function(error){
console.log(error) // see if anything is coming in error object
});
```

Answer (score 0):

My bad, I should use https://www.npmjs.com/package/request#forms package

```
request.post({url:config.OAUTH_ID_URL+'/oauth2/token', form: bodyData}, 
    function(err,httpResponse,body){
        console.log(err);
        console.log(body);
    })
```

It works now!!!
Thank you